# Asynchronous reading of multiple files in Tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I am trying to build a tiny status monitor for a server that broadcasts the information to a series of clients over a WebSocket. To that end, I am reading the output of several commands using [`tornado.process.Subprocess`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/process.html#tornado.process.Subprocess) as well as various files under the `/proc/` directory. I would like to know how I can asynchronously read the output of the different commands asynchronously, updating the dictionary of values that the WebSocket channels will broadcast to the clients.

I tried using `gen.coroutine` and `yield`ing an array with all the `DummyFuture` objects that each `Subprocess` call returns, unfortunately to no avail. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
def get_data(*args, **kwargs):
    response_dict = {}
    fd_uname = process.Subprocess("uname -r", shell=True, stdout=process.Subprocess.STREAM).stdout

    f_uname = fd_uname.read_until_close() # A DummyFuture is generated
    fd_uptime = process.Subprocess("uptime | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3 $4 $5}'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    f_uptime.read_until_close()

    # In the end, the results will be stored as entries of response_dict 

data_dict = {}
def process_data():
    result = get_data() # The goal is to run this function asynchronously
    data_dict = result

open_ws = set()
class WebSocketIndexHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        open_ws.add(self)
        self.callback = PeriodicCallback(self.send_data, 1000)
        self.callback.start()
        start_callback()

    def send_data(self):
        self.write_message(data_dict)

    def on_close(self):
        self.callback.stop()
        open_ws.remove(self)

ProcessCallback(get_data, 1000)
```

I thought of using the `callback` parameter of `read_until_close` as a solution, assigning another callback parameter to `get_data`) that would be called when all other futures resolve successfully, but I find that solution rather cumbersome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You also may look on [run_on_executor](http://blog.trukhanov.net/Running-synchronous-code-on-tornado-asynchronously/) decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a coroutine from another coroutine you need either "async def" and "await" in Python 3.5+, or else "gen.coroutine" and "yield". Here's the modern syntax:

```
async def get_data(*args, **kwargs):
    response_dict = {}
    fd_uname = process.Subprocess("uname -r", shell=True, stdout=process.Subprocess.STREAM).stdout

    uname_result = await fd_uname.read_until_close()
    fd_uptime = process.Subprocess("uptime | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3 $4 $5}'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    uptime_result = await f_uptime.read_until_close()

    # In the end, the results will be stored as entries of response_dict 
    return response_dict

async def process_data():
    result = await get_data() # The goal is to run this function asynchronously
    # Now do something with the result....
```

[Make sure you import subprocess from tornado, of course, not from the standard library.](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/process.html)

For more information, see the my [Refactoring Tornado Coroutines](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/) or the [Tornado coroutine guide](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html).

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to do it. Here is the current implementation, in case it is useful for someone: https://github.com/martinarroyo/deployer/blob/standalone/monitor/statuscrawler.py#L33